# How do I query results by a nested table property?

Tags: knex.js

I have a table `lead_check` that is joined to a table `prospect` which is joined to a table `account`. How can I query results such that `account.is_prospect` = `0`?

So far I am checking `lead_check` and calling `.joinRelated('prospect')` which works, but then chaining on `.joinRelated('account')` gives me the error `A model class LeadCheck doesn't have relation account` so I'm unable to check the value of `account.is_prospect`

This is the query so far:

```js
        const query = TridentLeadCheck.query()
            .alias('leadCheck')
            .select(
                'prospect.id',
                'leadCheck.success',
                'leadCheck.prospectId',
                'leadCheck.addedById as addedBy',
                'leadCheck.createdAt',
                'leadCheck.updatedAt',
            )
            .joinRelated('prospect')
            .orderBy(field, sort)
            .limit(limit)
            .offset(offset)
            .where({ success: 1 })
            .where({ 'prospect.status': 'pending' });
```

This is how I have attempted to get the value of `is_pending`:

```js
            query.joinRelated('account').where({ is_prospect: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just worked it out, posting the answer if anyone else has the same problem. You can join the nested account with square brackets:

```js
query.joinRelated('prospect.[account]').where({ is_prospect: 1 });
```